# quarantänefreies

Tags: adjective, gender, adjective-ending

I understood everything in this Tagesschau article except why in the following sentence it says quarantänefreies:

Die zwei Inselstaaten hatten im April einen beidseitigen Korridor für quarantänefreies Reisen geschaffen - die "Trans-Tasman bubble".

Shouldn't it say quarantänefreie or quarantänefreien instead? I mean, the -es ending would have been ok, if we were talking about a neuter noun in the singular, right?

https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/ozeanien/australien-grenzen-offen-corona-101.html

Comment: The question is about using  -es ending but the title is about... what?

Comment: It talks about "das Reisen". Which is a neuter noun in the singular.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I mean, the -es ending would have been ok, if we were talking about a neuter noun in the singular, right?

The text *is* talking about a neuter noun in the singular.

"Reisen", in this occurrence, is not the plural of "die Reise" (the journey), but rather the verb "reisen" converted into a noun, "das Reisen" (the traveling).

Answer (score 0):

As O. R. Mapper says, the *Reisen* is a neuter singular noun. This is example of a nominalized verb, in other words a verb (*reisen*) that's used as a noun. An example of nominalization in English is the noun "travel" from the verb "travel", as in the saying "Travel broadens the mind". A nominalized verb in German will be capitalized since all nouns in German start with a capital, and it takes the neuter grammatical gender. German uses nominalized verbs more frequently than English because it doesn't use the present participle (the "-ing" ending in English) as a noun as English does. Note that nominalized German verbs often don't appear in dictionaries; the rules for forming and using them is fairly universal so there's not much need. Although the meaning of a German nominalized verb is usually clear, it may need some creativity to translate it into English. For example *das Sehen* (literally "the seeing") is "vision" or "viewing".